# SKBitmap.Decode is returning NULL for some image files

Tags: decode, skiasharp

Can somebody help here.

I am using SkiaSharp 1.68.3 version in .Net Core 3.1 framework.
My requirement is to read the image file (raw file having >3 MB of size with various types like bmp, jpeg, jpg, tiff, png, gift etc) and need to resize with white background color etc and upload into blob storage.

The problem is when I use SKBitmap.Decode( ) method by passing the stream object of the image file, I am getting NULL occasionally. Here is the code, I am using and I don't understand where am I doing any mistake.

```
            try
            {
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    return (null, ImageErrorType.ImageFormatError, "Invalid Stream");
                }
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                
                var data = new BinaryReader(stream).ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                var imgInfo = SKBitmap.DecodeBounds(data);                
                if (imgInfo.IsEmpty)
                {
                    return (null, ImageErrorType.ImageFormatError, "Invalid Stream");
                }
                var bmp = SKBitmap.Decode(data, imgInfo);
                return (bmp, ImageErrorType.NoError, string.Empty);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (null, ImageErrorType.UnknownError, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                stream?.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
```

Here are the two images which is working and not working.

[Not Working Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttemo.jpg)

[Working Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdyvN.jpg)

Comment: I just noticed that the working image is created using Windows OS and Not working image is created using Macintosh OS. Does it matter any way ??

Comment: Try updating the skia sharp nuget version if possible. Both images work fine with 2.80.2.